# Can't immediately see data after committing sql transaction 

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, transactions

Updated for more direct title..

I am having an issue with seeing committed data from my transactions immediately after the commit.

I am accepting data from user input, putting data into the DB (SQL Server 2005) in the form of a parent table with multiple children tables with 1-many relationships. I am using a transaction and committing it when complete. The data is committed to the DB but I immediately run several other queries (`SELECT` statements only) against the DB after the commit to check to see if all the rows for a group have been entered. These rows can be entered at any time by anyone and are each in their own transaction. So, say the "group" has 3 total rows that are required in the database, I want to commit my transaction and then read the DB to see if ANY groups are complete...including that of the transaction I just committed.

The problem is that apparently reading the data back after the commit doesn't bring back the transaction I just committed... if this transaction is the last row in the group then it gets missed by the reads and doesn't return.

So...

- Transaction begins.
- write rows...
- transaction commits..
- read to see if complete groups exist...
- group with current transaction not returned.  other complete groups returned.

One thing to note, submitting another transaction will cause this data to be returned... if this new transaction contains a row to complete another group I do not get the new row returned...

Here is my code.. abbreviated...

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = getConn();  //getconn is a function that returns a connection object

String sqlSTR = "<<<MY INSERT STATEMENT>>>";
SqlTransaction trans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,"Trans");
SqlCommand sqlCMD;
try
{
    sqlCMD = new SqlCommand(sqlSTR, sqlConn, trans);

    //...Add all my data to the DB.

    trans.Commit();
catch (SqlException sqlErr)
{
    trans.Rollback("Trans");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    trans.Dispose();
}
```

Next is some code to read the DB looking for "completed groups" but the group this data belongs to, if completed, is not returned.

The data is stored... The data is retrievable by the same code by the next call.. but not here.

It's as if it takes time to commit the transaction by SQL and my reads are called BEFORE it's committed by SQL Server... even though I have the transaction set to allow reads to uncommitted data.

Is there someway to have the commit to wait for completion of the commit BEFORE moving on to other code?

I've tried doing a `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` against the connection immediately after the commit but it ALWAYS returns 0.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public static SqlConnection getConn()
{
    try
    {
        string sqlStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn_Main"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlCN = new SqlConnection(sqlStr);
        sqlCN.Open();

        return sqlCN;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm reading the records after the transaction by using a stored procedure...

In the SP I am using a basic select statement that does a couple of joins and not much else to pull back first a list of "groups" that have submissions and then each group individually pulls the individual groups.  It's the 2nd part that doesn't seem to see the records inserted with the transaction...  until the next transaction is committed.

I'm doing some more testing this morning to see if I can tell exactly when the records show up after committing the transaction.

Comment: Can you show what `getConn()` actually returns? Is it a connection string with `user instance` and `AttachDBFileName`? Can you show the code that is reading the data?

Comment: I updated the original to reflect some of the requested data.

Comment: The definition of `getConn()` does not help us. What is important is what it actually returns (e.g. the VALUE of `sqlStr` - we don't care where it comes from).